# Python 2.7, read file, when file's name is current date

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, text

I want to have text file's content printed in the label, but I have made, that every text file is saved and named by current date (for example: right now it would be saved as 2017_05_18). Is there a way to make ,that in the label I would get current day's text file info printed? And I mean not writing exact date by hand, but that it would automatically would pick current day's file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
current_date_str = current_date.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")
filename = current_date_str + ".txt"
```

so you will get a filename which is just named with current date.